# Does changing dependency versions in the pom.xml merit a version bump?

Tags: maven

Does changing a `pom.xml` dependency version merit incrementing that (dependent) project's version?

Answer (score 3):

Depends; does anything depend on the project in question?

If so, almost certainly yes, probably a point release.

If not, it's arbitrary: *I* would, because identifiable versions help recreate those previous versions.